# Angular js - resolve not passing parameters to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a issue where `angular` is not passing `resolve` parameters to `controller`.

```
route.js

var routingModule = require('../'); -- routing module is already defined, just injecting new routes

routingModule.config(myconfig);
myconfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
function myconfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home.clone', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/clone',
            template: '<ui-view/>'
        })
        .state('home.clone.dummy', {
            url: '/dummy?channelId',
            templateUrl: '/templates/clone_dummy.html',
            resolve:{

               simpleObj:  function(){    ---> it is not passing to controller 

                    return {value: 'simple!'};

                }

        },
        controller: 'makingCloneDummyCtrl',   ---> it is defined in another module
        controllerAs: 'rv', 
        date: {
            title: "Making Clone",
        }
    })
```

Here is the associated Controller below which is defined in another module which expects `simpleObj`

```
  controller.js

 angular.module('somemodule', [])
.controller('makingCloneDummyCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'simpleObj',
    function ($scope, simpleObj)
    {
        var self = this;

        console.debug(simpleObj);   ---> It prints function 
        console.debug(simpleObj.value);  ---> undefined 

    }
```

console.debug(simpleObj) prints below function

```
function Resource(value) {
      shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);
    }
```

while 
console.debug(simpleObj.value) prints `undefined`

I am not understanding what I am missing. 
May be controller is present in another module `somemodule` than routing module. Is this the reason `simpleObj` is not getting passed to controller ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what does `console.debug(simpleObj().value)` do?

Comment: @JohannesJander : undefined

Comment: @JohannesJander : Can you confirm me, is this issue not related if routing and controller are in different modules ?

Comment: You missed a comma in your string injection in the controller between $scope and simpleObj.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you missed a comma in you injection array.

Here is a working [plunker with a simplified setup](http://plnkr.co/edit/4QnGXuuge6yoomJ2x8mO?p=preview).

Just add to comma and you should be good to go.

```
 angular.module('somemodule', [])
   .controller('makingCloneDummyCtrl', [
     '$scope',   // Comma added here
     'simpleObj',
     function($scope, simpleObj) {
       var self = this;

       console.debug(simpleObj);
       console.debug(simpleObj.value);

     }
   ]);
```

Comment: Sorry I missed comma while posting question otherwise it is there in code

Comment: Ok, what is your routingModule = require(?)

Comment: It has var routingModule = require('../');  , ./index.js which has module.exports = angular.module('homeclone.routing', []);

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Normally you would just fetch the Angular module.

Comment: In plunker, in file route.js you have not included 'ui.router' still you are able to use '$stateProvider', how it is possible ?? I am sure I am missing some important concept.

Comment: It's added in the app.js file.

Comment: Ok , but routing module is not submodule of plunker then how come routing module inherits ui.router also .. Can you please redirect me to some documents regarding this which can clear my concept. Will be really helpful.

Comment: I think you have troubles understanding the syntax used in his plunk, have a look here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules